# Is there any manual way to kill an individual task in an executor in a spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, executor

When using spark shell, we sometimes get "Lost task 4 in stage 2.0" logs in between and the reasons could be numerous (eg., Out of memory/ executor killed etc.,). But is there any manual way to explicitly retrieve the tasks from an executor and kill it?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way for killing a single task, but you can kill a stage on Spark UI, which means there may be restful interface for killing stages.

Comment: Thanks! @bupt_ljy